# PHP registration form not processing

Tags: php

I am working on a registration form and am having an issue. No matter what I input into the fields on the form, whenever I hit submit, the form just clears and I never get forwarded to the homepage.php file. Does anyone see what is causing this file not to be read to? Thanks!

```
        <?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { // If the form was submitted, process it.

    //function to validate password
    function validatePassword($pass1,$pass2) { 
    if($pass1 === $pass2) 
        {         
          $msg = "Passwords match!"; 
        } 
        else 
        {
          $msg = "Passwords do not match!"; 
        } 
        return $msg;
}

    // Check the username.  
    if (preg_match ("^[[:alnum:]]+$", $_POST['username'])) {
        $a = TRUE;
    } else {
        $a = FALSE;
        $message[] = "Please enter a username that consists only of letters and numbers.";
    }

    // Check to make sure the password is long enough and of the right format. 
    if (preg_match ("^[[:alnum:]]{8,16}$", $_POST['pass1'])) {
            $b = TRUE;
    } else {
            $b = FALSE;
            $message[] = "Please enter a password that consists only of letters and numbers, between 8 and 16 characters long.";    
    }

    // Check to make sure the password matches the confirmed password. 
    if ($_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2']) {
            $c = TRUE;
            $password = crypt ($_POST['pass1']); // Encrypt the password.
    } else {
            $c = FALSE;
            $message[] = "The password you entered did not match the confirmed password.";  
    }

    // Check to make sure they entered a valid email address. 
    if (preg_match ("^([[:alnum:]]|_|\.|-)+@([[:alnum:]]|\.|-)+(\.)([a-z]{2,4})$", $_POST['email'])) { 
            $d = TRUE;
    } else {
            $d = FALSE;
            $message[] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }

    //  If the data passes all the tests, check to ensure a unique member name, then register them. 
    if ($a AND $b AND $c AND $d) {

        if ($fp = @fopen ("../writeable/users.txt", "r")) { // Open the file for reading.

            while ( !feof($fp) AND !$user_found ) { // Loop through each line checking, each username.
                $read_data = fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, "\t"); // Read the line into an array.
                if ($read_data[0] == $_POST['username']) {
                    $user_found = TRUE;
                }
            }
            fclose ($fp); // Close the file.

            if (!$user_found) { // If the username is OK, register them.

                if ($fp2 = @fopen ("../users.txt", "a")) { // Open the file for writing.
                    $write_data = $_POST['username'] . "\t" . $password . "\t" . $_POST['first_name'] . "\t" . $_POST['last_name'] . "\t" . $_POST['email'] . "\t" . $_POST['birth_month'] . "-" . $_POST['birth_day'] . "-" . $_POST['birth_year'] . "\n";
                    fwrite ($fp2, $write_data); 
                    fclose ($fp2);
                    $message = urlencode ("You have been successfully registered.");
                    header ("Location: homepage.php?message=$message"); // Send them on their way.
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $message[] = "Could not register to the user's file! Please contact the Webmaster for more information.<br />";         
                }
            } else {
                $message[] = "That username is already taken. Please select another.";          
            }

        } else { // If it couldn't open the file, print an error message.
            $message[] = "Could not read the user's file! Please contact the Webmaster for more information.<br />";
        }
    } 


} // End of Submit if.
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Print out any error messages.
if ($message) {
    echo "<div align=\"left\"><font color=red><b>The following problems occurred:</b><br />\n"; 
    foreach ($message as $key => $value) {
        echo "$value <br />\n"; 
    }
    echo "<p></p><b>Be sure to re-enter your passwords!</b></font></div><br />\n";  
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<table border="0" width="90%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Username</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="username" size="25" maxsize="16" value="<?=$_POST['username'] ?>"></td>
        <td align="left"><small>Maximum of 16 characters, stick to letters and numbers, no spaces, underscores, hyphens, etc.</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Password</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="password" name="pass1" size="25"></td>
        <td align="left"><small>Minimum of 8 characters, maximum of 16, stick to letters and numbers, no spaces, underscores, hyphens, etc.</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Confirm Password</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="password" name="pass2" size="25"></td>
        <td align="left"><small>Should be the same as the password.</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Email Address</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="email" size="25" maxsize="60" value="<?=$_POST['email'] ?>"></td>
        <td align="left"><small>Use whichever email address you want to receive notices at.</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register!"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 1: I have replaced the `$_POST` and `preg_match()` and instantly my code is doing more. However now when I submit the fields I get:

```
The following problems occurred:
Please enter a username that consists only of letters and numbers. 
Please enter a password that consists only of letters and numbers, between 8 and 16 characters long. 
Please enter a valid first name. 
Please enter a valid last name. 
Please enter a valid email address. 
Be sure to reenter your passwords and your birth date!
```

I'm not understanding why this is occuring since I am entering the information correctly into the fields. Any ideas?

EDIT 2: Here is the homepage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php # Script 4.2
if ($message) {
    $message = urldecode($message);
    echo "<div align=\"left\"><font color=blue><b>$message</b></font></div><br></br>\n";    
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is obsolete and has been for *years*. Start by writing code that hasn't been removed or deprecated and watch what happens.

Comment: @JohnConde what code is obsolete? Sorry I am new to php and just learning all of this.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding after seeing this removed or deprecated code *_* .. I must say please stop using PHP 4 :-|

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty I am sorry. I must have an old book that I am using. What would I need to do to make this more modern?

Comment: For starters, you need quotes around your `HTTP_POST_VARS` indexes, as in `$HTTP_POST_VARS['username']`. But [`HTTP_POST_VARS` is actually deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), and you should use $_POST (`$_POST['username']`).

Comment: @still2blue ... start following these "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCUV3iv9xOs&list=PL4EA8063603E83E5C" .. PHPacademy is really good . After that you should move to PHP 5.5 or PHP 5.6  to use the Full power of PHP :)

Comment: Would anyone be willing to re-write just one of my fields so I can see what the difference is? Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First of things  you have to use new resources to learn PHP, Because It Seems That You learn from an old book or tutorial.

use

```
   $ _POST
```

INSTEAD of

```
   $HTTP_POST_VARS
```

use also

```
   preg_match ()
```

INSTEAD of

```
   eregi ()
```

These resources can maybe help you to reach your goal

http://www.learn-php.org/

https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php

Comment: I have edited my original post. That certainly helped but I must still have errors somewhere.

Comment: Well, you have just to fill your form with valid inputs as your validation messages shows.

Comment: I am. I am following the criteria. It keeps the username and email in the fields already filled out but I have to keep entering the passwords and as far as I can tell, nothing is happening when I hit submit.

Comment: chekout your form action.

Comment: Is it not correct? I thought I would use post and set it to the register.php?

Comment: you have to check if there is the method and set it to post and then your action to whatever you want.

Comment: I am not understanding, could you show me please? Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Yes it is the file that I have posted. It's all one file called register.php

Comment: Yes it is on the server as well. When I go to it, nothing is displayed however since it is waiting for the form to validate itself. Right now I keep getting the same errors when I hit submit, it tells me to please enter a username with only letters, password thats 8-16 chars, and a valid email (all which I am entering are valid) it just wont get past this

Comment: Try to comment the part of validation.

Comment: If I remove all validation and hit submit, the page just goes blank

Comment: because your homepage.php doesn't contain anything.

Comment: It has code. It is set to display the message from the register page. The issue remains that my code is not working to get past that page in the first place.

Comment: Check edits. I put the validation back in (I have to have it) and added my homepage.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91990/discussion-between-abdelilah-aassou-and-still2blue).